# C# Use Expression to get value from an object

Tags: c#

the object cloud be any class, and I don't want to use reflection.
this is my code:

```cs
class Dog
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        static void test()
        {
            object d = new Dog
            {
                Id = 21,
                Name = "adsf"
            };
            genericeTest(d);
        }

        static void genericeTest<T>(T t)
        {
            var type = t.GetType();
            var arg = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
            var expr = Expression.Property(arg, "Id");
            var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(expr, arg).Compile();
            var value = compiled.Invoke(t);
        }
```

but there is exception `System.ArgumentException: ParameterExpression of type 'ExpressionDemo.Program+Dog' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object'`
at `var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(expr, arg).Compile();`

if I write like this

```cs
   var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<Dog, int>>(expr, arg).Compile();
   var value = compiled.Invoke(t as Dog);
```

it works well. can I fix it, thank you.

Comment: I have no clue what half of that code does, but perhaps a simpler solution would be good? You could use an interface so that your classes contain required values, or override the ToString method for each of your classes and then ToString the object. Sorry if I'm missing something which means that this wouldn't work.

Comment: declare d as Dog:  `Dog d = new Dog(...` or `var d=new Dog(..`

Comment: it's just sample code, I want to use expression to get value from object, the object is an instance of some class that is unsure, for example, it could be dog ,cat ,car ,person....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `T` is an `object`, because `d` has a compile-time type of `object`, but `t.GetType()` is `Dog`, because the runtime type of `t` is `Dog`.

So you've got an expression which accepts a `Dog`, but you're trying to pass it a variable of type `object` -- you're missing the cast which would turn the `object` into a `Dog`.

In other words, you're writing something roughly equivalent to:

```
public int GeneratedMethod(object o)
{
    Dog d = o; // <-- This line will cause a compile-time error, of course
    return d.Id;
}
```

The question is, what do you want your generated method to look like? Should it look like this?

```
public int GeneratedMethod(object o)
{
    Dog d = (Dog)o;
    return d.Id;
}
```

If so, you'll need to insert the cast from `object` to `Dog`. The way to do this is using [`Expression.Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.convert?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Convert_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Type_):

```
var type = t.GetType();
var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var expr = Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(arg, type), "Id");
var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(expr, arg).Compile();
```

Here we're declaring a lambda which accepts a `T`, but then casts it to `Dog`.

Comment: Or just use `Dog` instead of `object` :)

Comment: @DavidG I'm assuming that the OP is deliberately using `object` as the compile-time type of `d` for some reason: they know that everything works if they use `Dog`